# How to update row by group in sequence

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, rolling-computation, sequential

I have a dt:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4,5), b = c(4,5,6,7,8), c = c("X","X","X","Y","Y") )
```

I want to add one column d, within each group of column C:

- the first row value should be the same as `b[i]`,
- the second to last row within each group should be `d[i-1] + 2*b[i]`

Intended results:

```
   a b c d
1: 1 4 X 4
2: 2 5 X 14
3: 3 6 X 26
4: 4 7 Y 7
5: 5 8 Y 23
```

I tried to use functions such as shift but I struggle to update rows dynamically (so to speak) here,
wonder if there is any elegant data.table style solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we can use `accumulate`

```
library(purrr)
library(data.table)
DT[, d := accumulate(b, ~ .x + 2 *.y), by = c]
```

Or with `Reduce` and `accumulate = TRUE` from `base R`

```
DT[, d := Reduce(function(x, y) x + 2 * y, b, accumulate = TRUE), by = c]
```

Answer (score 6):

*We can use `cumsum` and subtract the first row using `[1]`:*

```r
DT[, d := cumsum(2 * b) - b[1], .(c)][]

#>    a b c  d
#> 1: 1 4 X  4
#> 2: 2 5 X 14
#> 3: 3 6 X 26
#> 4: 4 7 Y  7
#> 5: 5 8 Y 23
```